# How can one add an Epic link to a JIRA issue?

Tags: jira

I found that [answer](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-Core-Server-questions/How-do-I-add-an-existing-story-to-an-epic/qaq-p/123906) by [Thomas B](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/744438):

> Go to the story that you wish to add to the epic and follow these steps:
>
> 1. Edit > Epic Link > Click the drop down and select the Epic Link that matches what you want
> 2. If Epic Link is not showing on the Configured Fields, follow these steps:
>
>    1. Edit > Configure Fields (top right) > Select Epic Link
>    2. If Epic Link isn't shown, click "Where is my field?"
>    3. Scroll down and find Epic Link
>    4. Click on the blue hyperlink that says "....Screen configuration
>    5. Login as Admin
>    6. Select the Epic Link Field and repeat step 1

However:

- Epic Link is not showing on the Configured Fields.
- In Edit > Configure Fields (top right), I don't see "Epic Link".
- I don't see "Where is my field?".

[image]

How can one  add an Epic link to a JIRA issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list of fields depends on the issue type. In the JIRA project I am looking at, issues whose type is `initiative` have no Epic links:

[image]

while issues whose type is `task` have Epic links:

[image]